# Regular expression issue when using Generic Views in Django

Tags: regex, django, django-views, generics

I am a front-end developer currently dabbling into Django to build a simple portfolio site to display my work. I used Django quite regularly in my previous job but its now been over 6 months and unfortunately I do have old work to look over.

My site consists of:

A homepage with links to featured "projects"
A project list page
A project detail page

I am trying to take advantage of Django's Generic Views to create the latter 2 pages for me. However I am encountering issues when editing my urls.py file. Here it is:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
admin.autodiscover()
from django.views.generic import list_detail
from homepage.models import Project
projects_list_info = {
  'queryset' :   Project.objects.all(),
  'allow_empty': True,
  'template_name' : '../templates/project_list.html',
}

projects_detail_info = {
   'queryset' : Project.objects.all(),
   'template_object_name' : 'project',
   'slug' : 'slug',
   'slug_field' : 'slug',
   'template_name' : '../templates/project_detail.html',    
}


urlpatterns = patterns('',
   # Example:
   # (r'^howelltocode/', include('howelltocode.foo.urls')),
   # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
   # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
   # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:          
   (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   (r'^test','homepage.views.viewTest'),
   (r'^$','homepage.views.viewHome'),
   (r'projects/$', list_detail.object_list, projects_list_info),
   (r'^projects/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', list_detail.object_detail, projects_detail_info),    
   (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':     settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

The projects list view page successfully navigates to '/templates/project_list.html' when I type the url 'http://localhost:8000/projects'. However if I type 'http://localhost:8000/projects/htc-wildfire-facebook-application/' to view the "../templates/project_detail.html" page I get a 404 page with a "No project found matching your query" message.

I see this as encouraging as it obviously looking for a project but I think my regular expression could be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

You've overwritten the slug coming from the URL with the bare value "slug" in your projects_detail_info dictionary. Remove that entry from the dict.